# Swiftui EnvironmentObject UI is not updated in time

Tags: swiftui

I am a beginner in swift， I have a question about EnvironmentObject
I am trying to develop a GUI client for git
When I Clone a repository, I want a Popover that can view all the Clone tasks and progress
However, the progress of the Clone Task cannot be updated in time, and the progress of the previous Clone task will be updated only when a new Clone task is added (UI level, the data should be updated in my opinion).
Here is an example of mine Code

```swift
class CloneTaskModel: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
  var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  
  var title: String
  @Published var progress: CGFloat = 0
  
  init(title: String) {
    self.title = title
  }
  
  func start() {
    self.progress = 50
  }
}

class CloneTaskViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var tasks: [CloneTaskModel] = []
  
  func clone(title: String) {
    self.tasks.append(CloneTaskModel(title: title))
  }
  
  func deleteCloneTask(indexSet: IndexSet) {
    self.tasks.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
  }
}

struct ObservableObjectBootcamp: View {
  @StateObject var cloneTaskViewModel: CloneTaskViewModel = CloneTaskViewModel()
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
      List {
        ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { item in
          HStack {
            Text("\(item)")
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Clone", action: {
              cloneTaskViewModel.clone(title: "Task \(item)")
            })
          }
        }
      }
    } detail: {
      CloneTaskPopover()
        .environmentObject(cloneTaskViewModel)
    }
   
  }
}

struct CloneTaskPopover: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var cloneTaskViewModel: CloneTaskViewModel
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(cloneTaskViewModel.tasks) { task in
        HStack {
          Text(task.title)
            .font(.title)
          
          ProgressView(value: task.progress, total: 100)
          
          Button("Start") {
            task.start()
          }
        }
      }
      .onDelete(perform: cloneTaskViewModel.deleteCloneTask)
    }
    .navigationTitle("Clone Tasks")
  }
}
```

This is what happens in runtime.   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t3gR.gif).

I want the UI to update correctly in time when I click the Start button to update the Progress of the Clone Task

And I tried to change the CloneTaskModel from class to struct

```swift
struct CloneTaskModel: Identifiable {
  var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  
  var title: String
  var progress: CGFloat = 0
  
  init(title: String) {
    self.title = title
  }
  
  mutating func start() {
    self.progress = 50
  }
}
```

After this, i got an error message:    [error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28BSt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, only changes to the collection (`tasks`) will invalidate the view and that's why you get updates only when you add/remove objects. You have to directly observe the task objects.
You can simply refactor the code in your `ForEach` and extract to a new view:

```
struct CloneTaskView: View {
    @ObservedObject var task: CloneTaskModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(task.title)
                .font(.title)
            
            ProgressView(value: task.progress, total: 100)
            
            Button("Start") {
                task.start()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then your loop becomes:

```
ForEach(cloneTaskViewModel.tasks) { task in
    CloneTaskView(task: task)
}
.onDelete(perform: cloneTaskViewModel.deleteCloneTask)
```

which will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

definitely use a struct,

```
struct CloneTaskModel: Identifiable {...}
```

and (note the `$`)

```
 ForEach($cloneTaskViewModel.tasks) { $task in ...
```

in your `CloneTaskPopover`